# Is there something like stylus portable?

Tags: css, node.js, portability, stylus

So... In my school the computers are locked (I can't install software) Is there some way to run stylus (compile my stylus stuff) without installing node previously? Or some portable version of node that let me run stylus like it would in a normal machine? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [codepen](http://codepen.io) to compile stylus. If you've got an account just click the settings 'cog' on the CSS tab and choose 'stylus' as your preprocessor. After you put in your code you can click the 'eye' icon to view the compiled output. Run totally in the browser so installation shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/try.html without registration and any fee. This site is official, that's why you can use the latest Stylus features there.